# PHP - Parse mathematical equations inside strings

Tags: php, regex

I'm struggling to find the best way to do this. Basically I am provided strings that are like this with the task of printing out the string with the math parsed.

Jack has a [0.8*100]% chance of passing the test. Katie has a [(0.25 + 0.1)*100]% chance.

The mathematical equations are always encapsulated by square brackets. Why I'm dealing with strings like this is a long story, but I'd really appreciate the help!

Comment: preg_match_all + eval + str_replace (or with preg_replace_callback) ... in that order. but be warned, eval can be dangerous, dont just match on [] or someone could add code in [].

Comment: You can `eval()` the statements, that's a security risk though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
preg_match_all('/\[(.*?)\]/', $string, $out);
foreach ($out[1] as $k => $v)
{
    eval("\$result = $v;");
    $string = str_replace($out[0][$k], $result, $string);
}
```

This code is *highly* dangerous if the strings are user inputs because it allows *any* arbitrary code to be executed

Answer (score 3):

There are plenty of math evaluation libraries for PHP.  A quick web search turns up [this one](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/2695-PHP-Safely-evaluate-mathematical-expressions.html).

---

Writing your own parser is also an option, and if it's just basic arithmetic it shouldn't be *too* difficult.  With the resources out there, I'd stay away from this.

---

You could take a simpler approach and use [eval](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php).  Be careful to sanitize your input first.  On the [eval docs's page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php), there are comments with code to do that.  Here's one example:

*Disclaimer: I know eval is just a misspelling of evil, and it's a horrible horrible thing, and all that.  If used right, it has uses, though.*

```
<?php

$test = '2+3*pi';

// Remove whitespaces
$test = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $test);

$number = '(?:\d+(?:[,.]\d+)?|pi|π)'; // What is a number
$functions = '(?:sinh?|cosh?|tanh?|abs|acosh?|asinh?|atanh?|exp|log10|deg2rad|rad2deg|sqrt|ceil|floor|round)'; // Allowed PHP functions
$operators = '[+\/*\^%-]'; // Allowed math operators
$regexp = '/^(('.$number.'|'.$functions.'\s*\((?1)+\)|\((?1)+\))(?:'.$operators.'(?2))?)+$/'; // Final regexp, heavily using recursive patterns

if (preg_match($regexp, $q))
{
    $test = preg_replace('!pi|π!', 'pi()', $test); // Replace pi with pi function
    eval('$result = '.$test.';');
}
else
{
    $result = false;
}

?>
```

Comment: I agree except for the eval code sample (not working for me).

Answer (score 0):

The eval approach updated from PHP doc examples.

```
<?php
function calc($equation)
{
    // Remove whitespaces
    $equation = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $equation);
    echo "$equation\n";

    $number = '((?:0|[1-9]\d*)(?:\.\d*)?(?:[eE][+\-]?\d+)?|pi|π)'; // What is a number

    $functions = '(?:sinh?|cosh?|tanh?|acosh?|asinh?|atanh?|exp|log(10)?|deg2rad|rad2deg|sqrt|pow|abs|intval|ceil|floor|round|(mt_)?rand|gmp_fact)'; // Allowed PHP functions
    $operators = '[\/*\^\+-,]'; // Allowed math operators
    $regexp = '/^([+-]?('.$number.'|'.$functions.'\s*\((?1)+\)|\((?1)+\))(?:'.$operators.'(?1))?)+$/'; // Final regexp, heavily using recursive patterns

    if (preg_match($regexp, $equation))
    {
        $equation = preg_replace('!pi|π!', 'pi()', $equation); // Replace pi with pi function
        echo "$equation\n";
        eval('$result = '.$equation.';');
    }
    else
    {
        $result = false;
    }
    return $result;
}
?>
```

Answer (score -2):

Sounds, like your homework....but whatever.

You need to use string manipulation php has a lot of built in functions so your in luck.  Check out the explode() function for sure and str_split().

Here is a full list of functions specifically related to strings: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ref_string.asp

Good Luck.

Comment: Not homework... maybe you got that impression from my fictitious example? explode() is a pretty sketchy idea.